# Creating lists from the dictionary or just simply sort it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
import os
import pprint

file_path = input("Please, enter the path to the file: ")
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    worker_dict = {}
    k = 1
    for line in open(file_path,'r'):
        split_line = line.split()
        worker = 'worker{}'.format(k)
        worker_name = '{}_{}'.format(worker, 'name')
        worker_yob = '{}_{}'.format(worker, 'yob')
        worker_job = '{}_{}'.format(worker, 'job')
        worker_salary = '{}_{}'.format(worker, 'salary')
        worker_dict[worker_name] = ' '.join(split_line[0:2])
        worker_dict[worker_yob] = ' '.join(split_line[2:3])
        worker_dict[worker_job] = ' '.join(split_line[3:4])
        worker_dict[worker_salary] = ' '.join(split_line[4:5])
        k += 1
else:
    print('Error: Invalid file path')
```

File:

```
John Snow 1967 CEO 3400$ 
Adam Brown 1954 engineer 1200$
```

Output from worker_dict:

```
{
 'worker1_job': 'CEO',
 'worker1_name': 'John Snow',
 'worker1_salary': '3400$',
 'worker1_yob': '1967',
 'worker2_job': 'engineer',
 'worker2_name': 'Adam Brown',
 'worker2_salary': '1200$',
 'worker2_yob': '1954',
}
```

And I want to sort data by worker name and after that by salary. So my idea was to create a separate list with salaries and worker names to sort. But I have problems with filling it, maybe there is a more elegant way to solve my problem?

Comment: Make a list of dicts with `{'job': 'CEO', 'name': …}` instead? You can also use class instances instead of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pprint

file_path = input("Please, enter the path to the file: ")
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    worker_dict = {}
    k = 1
    with open(file_path,'r') as file:
        content=file.read().splitlines()
    res=[]
    for i in content:
        val = i.split()
        name = [" ".join([val[0],val[1]]),]#concatenate first name and last name
        i=name+val[2:] #prepend name
        res.append(i) #append modified value to new list
    res.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])#sort by salary
    print res
    res.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])#sort by name
    print res
```

Output:

```
[['Adam Brown', '1954', 'engineer', '1200$'], ['John Snow', '1967', 'CEO', '3400$']]
[['Adam Brown', '1954', 'engineer', '1200$'], ['John Snow', '1967', 'CEO', '3400$']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
 'worker1_job': 'CEO',
 'worker1_name': 'John Snow',
 'worker1_salary': '3400$',
 'worker1_yob': '1967',
 'worker2_job': 'engineer',
 'worker2_name': 'Adam Brown',
 'worker2_salary': '1200$',
 'worker2_yob': '1954',
}

from itertools import zip_longest

#re-group: 
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
      "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
       # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
       args = [iter(iterable)] * n
       return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

#re-order: 
res = []
for group in list(grouper(d.values(), 4)):
          reorder = [1,2,0,3]
          res.append([ group[i] for i in reorder])

#sort:
res.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
```

output:

```
[['Adam Brown', '1200$', 'engineer', '1954'],
 ['John Snow', '3400$', 'CEO', '1967']]
```

Grouper is defined and explained in itertools. I've grouped your dictionary by records pertaining to each worker, returned it as a reordered list of lists. As lists, I sort them by the name and salary. This is solution is modular: it distinctly groups, re-orders and sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to store the workers in a different format, for example [.csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), then you could use `csv.DictReader` and put it into a list of dictionaries (this would also allow you to use jobs, names, etc. with more words like "tomb raider").

Note that you have to convert the year of birth and salary to ints or floats to sort them correctly, otherwise they would get sorted lexicographically as in a real world dictionary (book) because they are strings, e.g.:

```
>>> sorted(['100', '11', '1001'])
['100', '1001', '11']
```

To sort the list of dicts you can use `operator.itemgetter` as the key argument of `sorted`, instead of a lambda function, and just pass the desired key to itemgetter.

The `k` variable is useless, because it's just the `len` of the list.

The .csv file:

```
"name","year of birth","job","salary"
John Snow,1967,CEO,3400$
Adam Brown,1954,engineer,1200$
Lara Croft,1984,tomb raider,5600$
```

The .py file:

```
import os
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint


file_path = input('Please, enter the path to the file: ')
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', newline='') as f:
        worker_list = list(csv.DictReader(f))
        for worker in worker_list:
            worker['salary'] = int(worker['salary'].strip('$'))
            worker['year of birth'] = int(worker['year of birth'])

    pprint(worker_list)
    pprint(sorted(worker_list, key=itemgetter('name')))
    pprint(sorted(worker_list, key=itemgetter('salary')))
    pprint(sorted(worker_list, key=itemgetter('year of birth')))
```

You still need some error handling, if a int conversion fails, or just let the program crash.

Comment: Also, take a look at [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). :)